# Media Query to target specific class or id?

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, media

I am working on a 'gallery' section for a side project and I am trying to accomplish different methods of displaying the images depending on screensize. 
At desktop and tablet size it would display as a grid, similar to vsco.grid or apples photo stream grid. At phone size it displays in a horizontal scroll to view the images.

My question is it possible to target a specific id or class with a media query? Logic tells me yes but life is telling me no.

Example:

HTML

```
`<div class="photogrid" id="photoscroll">
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
</div>`
```

Is this something that is possible with my current organization?
I know that I can set them as:

```
`<div class="photogrid">
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
</div>
<div id="photoscroll">
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
</div>`
```

And have separate mediaqueries in that format, but I am trying to avoid having the images have to load twice. (wrong thinking maybe? I am not that experienced.)

Any help is appreciated, I apologize if this is an obvious answer, google was no help.

Comment: Yeah you can target both classes and ids. Media queries work the same as any other CSS with the exception that it looks at your screen size / device etc. You don't have to load it twice if your HTML layout and CSS are correct.

Comment: @putvande Thank you! I'll be working on this now.